# Affiliate links (Amazon and others)

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, faq-proposed, amazon, affiliate

I've just read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085618) (now deleted). What is the policy on putting affiliate tags into Amazon links on Stack Overflow? What about other affiliate links?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Personally, I would flag any affiliate links as spam.

Appropriate on your blog, but not on a public forum, IMO.

Comment: Unfortunately, even thought the question is closed, the affiliate links remain. Is it appropriate to edit these out (or replace them with yours Jeff)?

Comment: I'd just remove the links altogether and put the explanation in the edit reasons.

Comment: So imagine a link thats a useful answer to the question, but just happens to be an affiliate link. (Even better, one that has a clear disclosure.) Is that so bad it should be flagged as spam?

Comment: yes, it should be flagged as spam -- we don't allow users to directly advertise their businesses here (other than ambient links in their user profile) so why would we allow it here?

Comment: @Jeff I disagree with you, but this isn't my website. :)

Comment: I think markdown should automatically add a StackOverflow affiliate link. More revenue, less ads!

Comment: What about instances where both the poster and the person who follows the link get some non-monetary benefit? A little extra storage in Dropbox, for instance?

Comment: What about instances where the poster gets some non-monetary benefit such as a badge on Stack Exchange?

Comment: @JeffAtwood What if the link doesn't point directly to a website but use as a sample code? Like if I copied that from my own code as ref. Is that appropriate to be banned for that?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on this "decision" Jeff? What do you think is the problem with people posting affiliate links?

Comment: So should I mark as spam every post that contains a link to Amazon, since Stack Exchange add their affiliate links?

Comment: What is the principal here? Just *stating* something is different from arguing/justifying it. As currently framed, it at best seems to be arbitrary and capacious, at worst it seems to be SE wants to make sure they can add their affiliate links to other people's content (which is seems like they do). That seems particularly hypercritical - especially when the policy does not seem to be disclosed.

Comment: As long as the link is relevant, it just promotes quality answering (who would click on a link of a bad answer?). And writing good answers costs a lot of time to contributors.

Answer (score 15):

I think that [flagging any affiliate link as spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2727) is overly harsh. Posts should be **edited** to remove the affiliate indication in compliance with the policy. Put a link to this thread in the edit summary and leave a comment on one post so that the user is notified through their inbox.

Harsher measures should only be taken if a user keeps including affiliate links after having been pointed to the policy. If a user remains deaf to comments or rolls the affiliate link back in, flag one of their posts for moderator attention and explain the situation.

Note that [`amazon.com` links are automatically converted to use Stack Exchange's affiliate code.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26964/auto-inserting-stack-overflow-affiliate-into-all-amazon-book-links)

Answer (score 10):

I would say that if the affiliate links are not affecting the answer in any way, to leave them in. If a person gives a great answer that happens to include a few affiliate links, so long as those links are completely relevant, then there is no harm in it. Especially if Stack Exchange doesn't have a link of their own to the question.

My example would be [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/7547/2692). The same quality of answer is there with or without the affiliate links, but the affiliate links give the poster of the answer a chance to make a small amount of money that would otherwise be lost (Actually, the various service providers would essentially make that money, giving them completely free advertisement).

However, if a person is showing an obvious bias, or self-promoting products, then they should be removed completely and quickly.

Answer (score 9):

Depends on what is going on. If you are answering a question concerning books or products and you are giving examples of really good books, I would more or less look past it (because if they are the one giving me the product for the first time and I like it, I wouldn't mind giving them some kickback for the review).

If they are asking a question or something and it is more blatantly spam trying to sell products without any real value behind it (or if that review or link is not a good idea on that particular question/answer) then I will be like ChrisF and flag it as spam.

Comment: Actually David M did the flagging, I said I would be tempted but hadn't got round to it in this case.

Comment: I was referring to you "I'd be tempted to flag it as spam". I admit I didn't really read your answer thoroughly (it's still early!).

Comment: I did flag it, and to be honest had the poster not included the throwaway "here's another book with an affiliate link in it" at the end of his/her question I might have let it go!

Comment: As I mention in my updated answer it was the second link that clinched it for me too.