# Can Stack Exchange unroll the Share Button link?

Tags: feature-request, share-this

On every question on the Stack Exchange network, there's a link to share the page you're on. When you click on it, it let's you copy a link to the page with a "referrer number", to track who brought the most traffic to SE and give them some badges.

I've had two issues with the current implementation:

1. Can the title of the question be part of that URL? I mean sometimes one needs to shorten in (for texting/twitter) but most places (blogs or *gasp* social networks) don't need it. Let the incoming user see what question is he about to see. If this is impossible, then
2. Can SE unroll internal links in comments (so if I copy `http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75624/168570` it will automatically unroll to `http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75624/ban-dropbox-referral-affiliate-links`) This is specifically annoying in comments as people tend to post links to questions which are possibly dups.

I don't know why people use this feature within the SE network as you don't get referral points for linking on an SE page.

Comment: Titles can change, and are often changed. So having a title shared publicly just to have it totally different in the actual page won't be a good idea.

Comment: Also, what you mean by "unroll"? Didn't get it from  your example.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I think unroll = unveil ~ implement...

Comment: I disagree with #1 (and therefore by the way your question is phrased, #2 as well), since *bloggers* typically refer to things using [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248573/168244) and [that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248573/168244). If you're referring to Facebook (as social networks), it loads a hyperlink as part of an edit, showing the viewer a visual of the intended target.

Comment: @Werner yeah, but by "will automatically unroll" does OP means do it when copying i.e. in the user's clipboard? Or when pasting? Or something else? :/

Comment: @Shmuel too bad you're not bothering to explain what you mean and ignore all the comments, you might have been able to save this request, I feel like I'm missing something. Too late now.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Sorry, busy until now. As for title change, we change titles in the post, why can't we change it in comments?

Comment: So your request here is to make http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248573/152859 turn into [Can Stack Exchange unroll the Share Button link?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248573) when posted in comment? If so, this [was already asked and declined](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77394/replace-links-with-the-current-question-title-in-comments)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Could be that way, or at least into http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77394/replace-links-with-the-current-question-title-in-comments

Comment: I didn't see that question

Comment: Well, it's really unclear from your question that this is what you really want. You didn't mention comments, you didn't mention title. Want me to edit your request into shape?

Comment: "I don't know why people use this feature within the SE network as you don't get referral points for linking on an SE page." – Oh, but [you do](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/76/publicist).

Comment: @AstroCB You get publicist even if the links are all local (so if I publicize this post on another SE question and 1000 people come to see it [unlikely :)] I'll get Publicist?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin It doesn't matter what the source is as long as you're using the referrer links – that's why your user ID is in the short link.

Comment: @AstroCB In that case the question makes no sense.

Comment: @AstroCB No, [Only clicks from outside the Stack Exchange network count towards the badge](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188733/259867)

Answer (score 2):

The format of the shareable URLs are short by design. If you want to elongate them, you need to just:

1. Open up a new tab
2. Paste in the share link
3. Watch as the URL expands
4. Copy the BOOMed out URL that now includes the title

If you wanted to just get the URL of the question, grab it from the question title which is a link itself.

Or from the location bar, unless you've jumped in directly to an answer.

Comment: if you use those links, will you get referrer credit when people follow them?

Comment: @KateGregory What is Referrer credit? (is there some kinda badge for this?)

Comment: @oxinabox absolutely! Scroll to the bottom of http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges to learn about Announcer/Booster/Publicist.

Comment: @KateGregory No, since they don't include UserId.

Comment: I don't need it when I comment. I need it when people put a whole list of links in comments and then I have to open it in order to see what they're talking about

Comment: @FamousBlueRaincoat Even if you use the code, it won't help since you don't get credit when linking on a SE site.