# How to post PDF for reproducing a bug?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I'm working on an issue that involves PDFs created in Foxit having problems being read in Adobe Reader, and creating a Foxit->Adobe converter app to solve this problem.

For posting questions about this issue, whether on StackOverflow or Superuser, I'll need to provide an example of a PDF created in Foxit that exhibits these problems when opened in Adobe Reader but [File-sharing service links like Dropbox and Google Drive contribute to link rot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266761/file-sharing-service-links-like-dropbox-and-google-drive-contribute-to-link-rot) seems to indicate that file sharing services are discouraged.

What is the proper way for me to link to an example file?

Comment: Could you create a screenshot of the issue (correct PDF vs bad PDF) and then upload that rather than uploading the file itself?

Comment: In that discussion I think they're referring to using them for code and images, which SE natively supports. If you could just upload your image or code into the question, it makes the question much more worthwhile.  However, since SE does not provide hosting for PDFs, I don't think it should be a problem for you to host it externally.

Comment: That's off topic on SO, and most likely on SU as well.  You should connect with Foxit and give them the PDF so they can determine what they are doing wrong.

Comment: The problem isn't really about how to link to an example, but how to ask a question that is self-contained enough that such a link would be a _reference_, not the core of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question would be on-topic on Stack Overflow if it was expressed as a programming problem. Given that you're creating a converter, that should give you a number of options.

As long as the bulk of the problem is in the question itself, including code examples that demonstrate specific problems you're facing, then providing links to an external host for the sample PDFs as references would be perfectly acceptable. Including screenshots of portions of PDFs to illustrate any visible problems would improve the question as well.

However, if the question is just "Here are some messed up PDFs, what's wrong with them?", the question is likely to be closed as off-topic or too broad on any site in the network.