# Affiliate Links

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Amazon affiliate tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2716/amazon-affiliate-tags)
>   [Using affiliate links in answer/question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7999/using-affliate-links-in-answer-question)

Is it against the TOS or at least frowned-upon to post affiliate links into stackexchange sites? I understand they need to be relevant to the asked question but is there a problem if I'm going to post a useful link anyway and happen to have an affiliate one?

Answer (score 0):

At best, do it like this.

[Here's a great link that will solve all your problems (affiliate link)](http://www.google.com)

But I've seen Jeff or others speak negatively about those kinds of links.