# This user is edit-spamming dozens of answers with their affiliate code. Can they be removed?

Tags: support, edits, spam

See the activity here: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1071887/idan?tab=activity&sort=revisions

Notice that most of the edits are simply adding that user's affiliate code to iTunes links.

It's a clever trick to try and get their code embedded into other people's apps.

I have reverted a few but there are so many. Can this user be deleted and all edits reverted?  These edits are certainly not adding any value to the SO community, and I suspect are in violation of the terms.

Comment: Wow, that account needs to be burninated. This is a case for a moderator flag.

Comment: And he has also some answers that should be removed for the same reason.

Comment: @ProgramFOX oh, missed the answers! Going to have a look now...

Comment: I think you really took that out of proportion making all community to attack me. Hope you are happy now.

Comment: @Idan you chose to edit-spam your affiliate link multiple times - so you brought this on yourself.

Comment: Popular precedence could make dictatorship on actively trying people (e.g. to get out of ban) and others of course. But let me describe my case. I've spent much time reading how to get out of ban. I just want to work. Why I'm not legal. Smth of mine is good including other resources (much worse than SE, of course). So you could put someone from active people into focus and make reputation on him and one that pointed the banhammer would be very pleased and get satisfaction of tortures. I'M NOW AFRAID of any activity (because of this bad precedence being set very handidly).

Comment: @Amaterasu Pay attention that some of the answers are now incorrect because of removing the affiliate, so not you just banned me but you have reduced the quality of the answer. For example pressing this: itunes.apple.com/album/id318390146 or pressing this: itunes.apple.com/album/id318390146?at=012345 (it's not my affiliate I promise) gets a different result (would not open store on Mac for example) so OS behaviour is different and now incorrect.

Comment: Working links here: 

1) http://itunes.apple.com/album/id318390146
2) http://itunes.apple.com/album/id318390146?at=012345 

Sorry.

Comment: @Idan can you link to the answers you believe legitimately need an affiliate code?  Such answers could include a discussion on the effect of adding such a code.

Comment: @WilliamDenniss I think all basically. It is pretty simple: From an app you can post to any social media so it would be properly that if the developer would want to users to get the store immediately (no matter which OS the target user is using) and not waiting for webpage and then  expect target user to press it he should use the affiliate code. I assume I should have probably add some disclaimer about that so if developer didn't want this option he would remove it. I think it include the app codes and the link to link maker which would produce the "better" links.

Comment: @WilliamDenniss I can write a detail post about that explaining how it would affect users eventually (maybe when I'll be out of ban). But it would be a lot longer than could be in a comment. Just to be clear I'm not willing to add/change any post ever till I fully understand it is/what is considered ok here...

Comment: @Idan: You make money on affiliate links when people buy something. THAT IS THE ONLY REASON TO INCLUDE AN AFFILIATE LINK. It does not make the link work any better or worse.

Comment: @Idan I did not get you banned - YOU got you banned, as mentioned above, affiliate links make you money, which is why they are not allowed.  I did not edit your posts (not even a member of SO), but would have gladly edited the affiliate code out if I were.
Understand this, **affiliate links are NOT allowed** END OF STORY.

Comment: @Amaterasu As I explained. Those links are for code and change the link behaviour (open the store directly) and not direct link to content. therefore improve the quality of answers which are now have less value.

Comment: @Idan you are not fooling anyone - affiliate links = money for you = not allowed on this site and has been mentioned - **will** be edited out.  Nothing you will say will convince me otherwise (nor many other members).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

A critical hit with the ban hammer has been dealt to the user. Unfortunately we don't have any way to bulk-revert edits - so anyone who's helping in rolling back those edits will get a virtual cookie from me.

Comment: Thanks. A 7 days' suspension seems way too soft for the criminal energy on display here, though. I'll write to the community team and petition that the account be terminated (not to spite or second-guess your decision, but I guess terminations would be handled by the community team anyway)

Comment: Is it OK to remove the `&at=` from his recent answers?

Comment: Yes, please remove that spammy crap wherever you find it!

Comment: By the way, @ThiefMaster is there a predefined suspension reason "promotional content" or is this a custom title? :)

Comment: Any clue why this other user [was using the same id](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21327847/revisions)...?

Comment: @Arjan ooooh. It could well be an innocent mistake (copy&pasted from elsewhere), but it seems definitely worth checking out

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Predefined reason, but with custom text since the default message doesn't fit in this case.

Comment: Terminating the account right now would make finding and reverting their edits a lot harder than it needs to be @Pëkka.

Comment: @Yannis that's a fair point, but the end result should be termination.

Comment: @Pëkka No argument there, and I suspect the short suspension was only meant to stop them from doing any more edits until the community has time to clean up the mess.

Comment: It seems, though, he's got decent questions and answers otherwise, though (unless I'm missing something, and considering I only took a cursory glance through those...)

Comment: Yeah, his content is good otherwise. It should definitely survive the burnination.

Comment: Indeed, @Pękkä, the other user posted [their answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21327847/revisions) on January 24th, so probably copied something after an earlier edit of the abusive user, which started earlier than that date.

Comment: Guys, It was just a stupid mistake. I've improved tons of answers during almost 3 years I'm on this site. You can check it all out and see the value in it (had more than 3000 points before this ban). This was just copy&paste mistake from my code, no need to be too aggressive.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13780166/revisions | http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3724728/revisions | http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8803352/revisions

Comment: @ThiefMaster Except 1 link you post (showing only adding at link) the other shows deleting the country code etc getting from linkmaker which is critical if you want the link to work on other countries then the "us" also deleting app name which is also critical because it is subject to change. I know I did mistakes yesterday and sorry for that but follow my 3 years of work I provide huge value to StackOverflow. This week ban is more than enough for this mistake.

Comment: The few that ThiefMaster listed are not the only ones, @Idan, and I only checked a random few: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2337601/revisions, http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4122371/revisions, ...

Comment: @Pekka Yes, My original old answers was with affiliate links you removed. I didn't copy that from my code deliberately knor I know that it is forbidden (I can copy my code directly but now be more careful). Anyway, I said what I had to. If you take your time you would see the long lasting value I'm providing and not judge by yesterday...
And please don't call me names because this is surely forbidden.

Comment: @Arjan Yes, I admit I did mistakes yesterday. Please take your time and check my other answers. hope you would see I'm bringing huge value on questions no one does.
And this mistake won't ever happen again.

Comment: @ThiefMaster By the way, Please take a look at this post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7999/using-affiliate-links-in-answer-question# 

Links are been taken from my original post and according to the answers there this isn't forbidden to have a link when a relevant answer (just an opinion there). So, It is kind of weird that changing my originals answers to be without it (using community). I get that changing others answers even if it adds value shouldn't be with affiliate. but to my real answers it is absurd and you have a big list of users to ban if this is the policy.

Comment: @ThiefMaster The real thing here is that this affiliate isn't working in the site. It doesn't point to my apps unless you copy and use your app for that so it isn't spam the site as to adding pointers to a webpage etc.

So, Please if you ban me please ban all other users that use affiliate link on their answers. Otherwise please bring me back. I won't edit no ones answer ever again even if the answer is crappy.

Comment: You are very welcome to edit any post containing an affiliate ID and remove it :)

Comment: @ThiefMaster Now I cannot even edit my own posts :)

Comment: Where in [Using affiliate links in answer/question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7999/using-affiliate-links-in-answer-question) do you see that the community feels it's okay to have such links, @Idan? I read exactly the opposite. (Even more so for *hidden* affiliate ids.)

Comment: @Arjan I understood that if it is a legitimate answer there is no law against it. We both agree that changing other posts for that reason is spam like hidden affiliate on the discussion. But if my answer contain a code that could be affiliate (not hidden affiliate to be on Google's radar) it seems legit or at least not spam according to stackoverflow terms. Just wondering...

Comment: @Idan I think the problem is moreof you were replacing *working* links with a link with your affiliate id. It didn't improve the quality of the answer at all.

Comment: @hichris123 I was super tired yesterday and did mistakes (some added value some very ugly spammy mistakes). Those mistakes were fixed today by community but I was also banned from the website and also all my real answer which where my own only was edited to remove the affiliate (those answers got huge points and reputation). Which seems absurd.
I agree that yesterday I did mistake, but I'm on this site for 3 years with amazing reputation I've built, it isn't ok that all my relevant genuine answers was edited by those guys without taking into consideration the website policy.

Comment: Those weren't "mistakes". They were deliberate actions.

Comment: @Pëkka Thanks for the support! What do you think about affiliate code sample on your own relevant answers? (not changing others posts nor using a working link to a website).

Comment: @Idan I'm siding with Jeff Atwood in his answer to [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2716/affiliate-links-amazon-and-others). Affiliate links are spam. Continued posting of affiliate links should lead to a temporary ban. Editing your own affiliate ID into other people's answers should result in immediate account termination, IMO.

Comment: @Pëkka - While I appreciate that people strongly oppose what was done here, they have enough of a history that I'm willing to hear them out. We reserve forced deletion of accounts for clear sock puppets or spammers with no other redeeming value. They clearly are not an account created only to spam, and if they've learned from what went wrong and won't ever do this again, I have no problem with them continuing on the site. Account deletion or suspension isn't there for punishment, it's to make sure that bad behavior stops immediately. I'd much rather educate than ban.

Comment: @BradLarson Thank you very much! I would sure won't ever do this mistake again and sadly would think twitch before changing anyones answer (this ban waste me few work hours which is a waste I can't afford). You can probably see my value provided to the iOS scene on this site. I still didn't get any clear answer about using this kind of affiliate on my own genuine sample code I've provided. I don't plan to add it till I would be 100% sure it is legit by the website and by community but still interesting question. it was too easy for community to ban me but edit my great legit answers for pts

Comment: @Brad I see where you're coming from, but I disagree in this case because it's so easy to imagine  this kind of stuff slipping under the radar. A 1-week suspension is a signal to jokers like this guy to try and see whether they can get away with it (and let's face it, that's what happened here. Editing your affiliate ID into someone else's 5 years old answer a "mistake"? The result of being "tired"? Give me a f-ing break.) I don't think the worst you should have to fear in such a case is a slap on the wrist.

Comment: @Pëkka There are some users making their reputation by interfering other to add real value to this site. Please take your time and read my answers in-depth, If you would feel like I'm a spammer (remove yesterday edits) I promise I would go off this site. I do think that I add value no one else does.

Comment: @Idan I do not disagree your track record so far looks fine. Whether that's an excuse for what you did, while knowing full well what you were doing, is a different question. (It's not my decision either way.)

Comment: @Pëkka Although I had great reputation I'm really sorry I didn't took the time to understand all relevant expected behaviours on this website. What I'm saying is that I just post answers and great ones. I didn't know what I did is spammy and thought legit. I was super tired yesterday and didn't think through (was a long day). From this mistakes (yes this is how I see it) to a ban, removing all my answers and take credit for that (even though those were my genuine answers now looks like I did all for a crappy affiliate) there is a huge difference.

Comment: @Pëkka I think if someone was just explaining to me the wrong thing I did I would take the hours and fix everything myself.
I'm not here to spam the site in any way. Attacking me this way (and attacking me personally like you did) is really out of proportion.

Comment: The fact that you came here and defended yourself, in a constructive way, is a good sign, @Idan. Most spammers don't. That doesn't take away from the fact that you *did* spam, and I think Pëkka's response is justifiable. But thanks for showing up here.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta I want to make sure everyone understand I'm not here to spam. The text here is out of proportion to the actual act which I didn't understood as spam act yesterday. On the other hand calling me names like Pekka did is really offending and unacceptable! Moreover, Banning me and using my edits and original answers but removing the affiliate which aren't illegal on this website (when using as explained earlier) is just making me less believe on this site. Seems that there are developers which add real value and some others that just looking to add points to their profile.

Comment: "Banning me and using my edits and original answers **but removing the affiliate**" - did you just admit that you added those affiliate IDs on purpose to get more than just reputation from your answers?!

Comment: ...and now you're making things worse, @Idan. You are a spammer because you [have](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8803352/revisions) [spammed](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13780166/revisions) [repeatedly](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3724728/revisions). There is no question about this fact, Idan. Accept this, apologize, stop lashing out, and move on. Maybe you didn't understand this as spamming until today (I'm not sure I believe this, but it's possible). Well, now you do, and you understand that this is considered abuse. Right?

Comment: There is absolutely no way one - let alone a 3000 rep user! - could edit a question *with the sole purpose* of inserting an affiliate ID into it and somehow not know this was a major breach of the rules.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Why making thinks worse? Yes, I do understand that I cannot edit others posts. I won't ever add any affiliate link to a post/answer that is not mine. But still want an answer about my own posts (which I won't also add affiliate unless I'm 100% sure it's legit as claimed earlier).

Comment: When would an affiliate link ever be needed for a post to make sense? PS: the post you refer to explicitly states it is *not* allowed to add affiliate links. **In summary, no affiliate links in answers, even if the answer is otherwise good, useful, etc.**

Comment: @Idan *Why making thinks worse?* Because it's concerning that you're not taking responsibility for your actions, for something you knew was wrong. As far as your own posts, you might get an official or semi-official response, but I'd advise that you don't add any affiliate links. For better or worse, eyes will be on you for a little while, and those links will be edited out.

Comment: @ThiefMaster No! If you look at what community did: they didn't revert my answers as a whole but keep my great answers and removed the affiliate link to get credit (means my asters had some value although you all claim it is total spam). It's not what I did but the community. As claimed earlier I won't use affiliate in any way unless I'm 100% sure it's legit. For now I understand that only others posts is probably not legit (sure edit posts just for that). No-one knows the answer to the other "grey" questions but still I'm banned for it.

Comment: Affiliate links are not legitimate in one's own answers, either, and are subject to being edited out. See Jeff's answer in the link above.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta You probably didn't read all this long comments :). I claim that I won't ever post any affiliate link unless I'm 100% sure it is legit. and yes I would get a formal answer for that. Moreover, I would sadly consider 3 times before changing any old un-relevant answer like I did yesterday.

Comment: @Pëkka Jeff wrote his opinion, You can see others claiming otherwise. I would try to get some formal answer about it. This is a very interesting issue.

Comment: Here is it again from a mod: **Affiliate links are a no-no.**

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta I do take responsibility to my action and did apologise directly to moderator. As said over and over I won't do that in any case but if 100% sure it's legit. On the other hand I don't like people calling me names.

Comment: @ThiefMaster I already know this is your opinion. Easy to say no. We would check what is needed to get a yes (disclaimer/own post/whatever) from official (no offence mod :) ). Anyway, I promise not to do anything before getting that answer and post that here.

Comment: I really don't know what else you expect, when you've gotten an answer from a moderator and the site co-founder :) You've received as official an answer as you're likely to get.

Comment: Interesting that Stackoverflow change all amazon affiliate to their affiliate links. Does that means amazon affiliate links is acceptable? If that is so why iTunes isn't?

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26964/auto-inserting-stack-overflow-affiliate-into-all-amazon-book-links

Comment: No, it does not, @Idan. What it means is that the site itself reserves the right to insert affiliate links. Not everyone was happy about that, but that's different than your situation, in that you're not Stack Overflow, and Stack Overflow is.

Comment: Jeff Atwood is the site's founder. This site is ruled by a mixture of  moderator and community consensus, Jeff's Word, and a few official rules. There is no need for some kind of official statement. The question whether affiliate links are okay or not is settled.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta You are probably right. getting a yes for those things going to be hard... :)

What is your opinion? Is there any way you think it could be legit?

Comment: Legit, to add affiliate links to your own content, @Idan? No, I do not. It's hard to express why, in a short comment, but quickly: we should keep the financial incentive out of the site. No "$20 to write me a script". No "here's a link to my ad-supported blog on every answer". No affiliate links. Money tends to drive sites in bad directions, and incentivises the wrong behaviors. You get crummy questions, slanted answers, and a really bad taste.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta You are right on those cases. But if it is a code of yours, should you censor it from any affiliate? If I point to my own app in code (I can see this everywhere) isn't that more inappropriate?

Comment: Things are rarely black and white, @Idan, but clearly your opinion of where to draw the line is far from community consensus. Understand that, and play it safe in this area. Point to your app *if and only if doing so improves your question*. If it doesn't, if you're just mentioning the app that contains the code or functionality you have questions about, leave it out.

Comment: And yes, people link to their app all the time, often when it's not necessary. If there's a trend, if it seems abusive, you'll often see the mention edited out.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Sure but on my original answers the code was part of my original code which is super relevant to the case. So, Did I do wrong not censor that one?

Comment: *Did I do wrong not censor that one?* Representative link, @Idan?

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18905686/itunes-review-url-and-ios-7-ask-user-to-rate-our-app-appstore-show-a-blank-pag/18907231#18907231

Comment: You *added* an affiliate link in revision 3, @Idan, six weeks after the original answer. Your question does not apply. That's clearly wrong.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta I would need the bigger picture. If there were no revisions. Would that be relevant enough?

Comment: If it's not fundamental to the question asked, then no.

Comment: No, it's never relevant unless it actually concerns the question. What is wrong here is that you deliberately added it to pre-existing questions which put the spotlight on you. If you hadn't, these things would've probably gone unnoticed. They shouldn't be in SO, but they're easy to forget so you are given the benefit of the doubt for not knowing. If it is a pattern of behaviour then it will be seen as a bad thing, if it isn't then we might overlook it.

Comment: No, it's not ok, if it's not relevant to the question. Even if the question is specifically about affiliate links, you should replace your identifier with a placeholder, the same way you see domains often replaced with *example.com*. Good luck after your suspension, @Idan, I have to leave now.

Comment: @Idan, all edits made should should improve the answer. Appending unnecessary information to these URLs has made the answer worse, and additionally was done to profit yourself. You are spreading misinformation – people may think that the affiliate code you added is a necessary part of Apple's URL scheme – and are profiting from doing so. This is obviously a bad thing, in my opinion.

Comment: @ThiefMaster thanks for the ban. Can direct-edit privileges be removes from this user? It's harder to catch minor edits like this when done in this way, perhaps all future edits by this user should be peer-reviewed, as if he was a low-rep user?

Comment: @WilliamDenniss Why are you trying to punish me personally? I have great reputation, won't do this again and sure you would use your precious time to make sure I won't. and I won't. ever! 
Anyway, There are lots lots of affiliate links on SO you can find and ban/ take your aggression out so you have what to do next on this website...
I'm just thinking a small comment/edit out one of the post was enough for users like me and not trying to punish on whatever scale you can...

Comment: @WilliamDenniss such thing is not possible, moderator can only block users from *reviewing* (same way as if they failed too many audits) but can't revoke privileges like editing. Maybe a dev can do that by manual change in the database but I doubt it's worth the hassle... on such cases we just keep an open eye and in the next offense I'm pretty sure the account will be nuked, or suspended for years. Anyway in this specific case I tend to believe Idan that it won't happen again.

Comment: @Idan I care about the quality of this site, your actions were reducing it, it's that simple. Thank you for your pledge to stop that behavior. I agree with Shadow Wizard, we should take you at your word, I hope you don't abuse our trust.

Comment: @WilliamDenniss ShadowWizard Thanks for your trust.

Comment: Hey all, Just remembered what made me add affiliate in first place. OS behaves different when using affiliate or not. Pressing this: http://itunes.apple.com/album/id318390146 or pressing this: http://itunes.apple.com/album/id318390146?at=012345 (it's not my affiliate I promise) gets a different result (would not open store on Mac for example/I assume same behaviour on Windows and for some versions of iOS). Some answers are now incorrect or would have the user to get at least one more click to open iTunes.

Answer (score 30):

This situation could not have arisen with Amazon affiliate links, since the Stack Exchange software [automatically rewrites them to use Stack Exchange's own affiliate code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26964/auto-inserting-stack-overflow-affiliate-into-all-amazon-book-links).

Given this precedent, would it not make sense to extend this feature to also **automatically strip affiliate codes** from links to iTunes, and to any other popular websites with an affiliate program (e.g. eBay)?

Doing so would:

- eliminate any incentive for people to try to inappropriately sneak affiliate links into posts, whether their own or others',
- eliminate any risk of good-faith users being accused of spamming just because they happened to include an affiliate code in their links, and
- if the links were changed to use an SE affiliate code, possibly earn Stack Exchange a bit of extra money with which to keep the site up and running.

That sounds like a win/win/win situation to me.

Comment: How big is this of a use-case except to clean up the mess caused by this user?

Comment: @JanDvorak: That's a good question. It would be interesting to see how many existing posts with iTunes affiliate links there are on, say, SO, but I'm not sure how to figure that out. Maybe by downloading and parsing a data dump? In any case, the fact that one user tried this and got caught does suggests that, sooner or later, someone else is likely to have the same idea (if they haven't already).

Comment: I've quickly tossed together http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/166293/itunes-affiliate-hunting and did find a *very* few older posts that contained affiliate IDs in them (the query is light enough you can do an entire year at a time).  Do note that this doesn't identify things that have been cleaned up in the past as they were found - so while I only found a very few, there could have been quite a few more that were edited out.

Comment: @MichaelT: Thanks!  You might find a few more if you also looks for `&at=` in addition to `?at=`.

Comment: In this specific case, the affiliate id was added to code blocks (not to clickable links), where the editor seemed to be hoping that the id would somehow end up in the source code of whoever used the snippet. (I don't know what's to gain there, but for me trying to get into someone's source code is even worse than adding it to some clickable URL.) I'm afraid that automatically changing code blocks will result in a lot of errors.

Comment: @Arjan: Good point. If all the edits were indeed to code blocks / backticked code, then my proposal would not have actually helped here.  You're right that we shouldn't be auto-mangling URLs that are not actually links; the existing Amazon rewrite doesn't, either, and that's a *very* good thing.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen What if removing the affiliate code make the answer wrong? What if behaviour of OS is going to be different by that. Is that illegal also?

Comment: @Idan: If showing the affiliate code in the URL really was an important part of an answer, one could always e.g. wrap the URL in backticks to de-link it. (Even then, it would be good form *not* to use a real affiliate code, but instead write something like, say, `https://itunes.apple.com/album/id<album_id>?at=<affiliate_code>` with placeholders for the code and ID.)

Comment: To get an affiliate ID you need to do some progress. I believe it's easier just to use that, if the user have his own he would probably change that to his...

Answer (score 25):

Let's take the whole spammyness of the affiliate links out of the equation, and what this boils down to is just vandalism. Vandalism on any of our sites will quickly get you suspended or shown the proverbial door, so we highly recommend not doing that, or anything else, that intentionally lowers the perceived quality of our combined work.

Don't trigger on *just* seeing an affiliate link of some kind - some sites give you sharing buttons automatically encoded with affiliate information even if you're not part of the program, and folks don't even realize what they're pasting - they just think it's a link.

Trigger on the perceived *intent* when it comes to vandalism. If the person is doing it serially, and it's hard to argue that they *aren't* aware of how inappropriate such a thing is, then we will take very swift and decisive action. But, that's up to the moderators and us, the community team.

Remember that the whole point of suspension is to get problematic behavior to *stop*, and suspensions should last *precisely* the amount of time needed to make that happen. I don't want to get into territory where we set up mandatory 'sentencing' for different kinds of infractions.

However, I will say this, if you deliberately and *repeatedly* vandalize one of our sites, you're going to have a pretty hard time convincing us that you should be able to access them at *all* beyond reading, and we've got pretty comprehensive facilities in place to make that happen.

Comment: I've purged comments under this answer because I really don't need the hassle of users calling one another morons flying through my inbox. Please, take my advice and just ***drop it***. Thanks.