# Prevent edits of under 6 characters of your own post from bumping it to the top of the active list

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits, spelling, too-minor

So...I just found a typo in one of my old posts.  It's only one character off.  On the one hand, I want to fix it because I'd like my posts to be typo-free.  On the other hand, I don't want to look like one of those people who make small edits to their posts just to get them repeatedly bumped to the top of the active questions list.

Feature request: **If I make an edit of fewer than six characters to one of my own posts, it should not bump that post to the top of the active list.**  (The same should hold true for any change to the formatting of one of my own posts; going back to boldface or italicize keywords in my own posts should not bump them to the top of the list.)

Note: I'm suggesting this feature for only your own posts.  Even a tiny edit to another user's post would still get bumped.  Also, any edit to a link should always cause the post to be bumped (in order to prevent sneaky changes of link suffixes with compact URLs, an issue which @MichaelT raised below).

---

Points for discussion are:

- whether this feature should only apply once you reach a certain privilege level (1000, perhaps?)
- whether it should apply to tag edits of your own questions
- whether the limit should be lower than the tiny-edit limit of six characters. (Fixing typos would often require only one or two characters.)

Answer (score 7):

No.

A couple of months ago, there was [an issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220158/this-user-is-edit-spamming-dozens-of-answers-with-their-affiliate-code-can-they) where a user was adding their affiliate code to their posts ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13780166/revisions)).  This was noticed because the posts got bumped.

And while you may say "But that was 11 characters to add `/?at=XXXXXX`, That's above my threshold of 6" - the point is that people can and will do this and can try to game the system to do so (and some may have shorter links).

Bumping the post for *any* edit allows people to once again look at it and identify if everything there is correct and in accordance with site policies.

Comment: one particular way I can think of to stay under radar of "minor changes" if I was a spammer is to search for URL shorteners in posts and replace their link IDs to mine

Comment: The example you give was not someone editing their own post.  It was someone editing other people's posts.  I'm proposing this feature **only for edits of your own post**.  If you turn your own post into spam, people will downvote it, which is self-fixing.

Comment: @3nafish then consider the situation where these edits are put in after the fact.  Its an example of someone modifying a short string that would make a link be something that would otherwise be frowned upon by the community.  This could be bit.ly links or an imgur image.  The key is all edits bump the post so that eyeballs can look at it again to make sure that it is still a proper edit.

Comment: @MichaelT, that would still be easy to prevent if this rule only applied to edits that didn't modify links.  I'll edit my post to reflect this.  Thanks.